# Improve this SQL Query for better performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case-statement

DBA does not like that I am using case statements with sub-queries.  Is there another approach I could take to improve performance?  This update statement is a part of stored proc.

```
    UPDATE dbo.CMN_PersonsFerpa 
    SET 
        IsWorkEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN (SELECT EmailType FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID) =  'Work'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsWorkEmailFerpa END,
        IsPersonalEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN (SELECT EmailType FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID) =  'Personal'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsPersonalEmailFerpa END,
        IsParentEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN (SELECT EmailType FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID) =  'Parent'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsParentEmailFerpa END,
        IsTempEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN (SELECT EmailType FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID) =  'Temporary'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsTempEmailFerpa END,
        IsFAFSAEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN (SELECT EmailType FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID) =  'FAFSA'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsFAFSAEmailFerpa END,
        IsCSSProfEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN (SELECT EmailType FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID) =  'CSS Profile'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsCSSProfEmailFerpa END,
        IsCommenceEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN (SELECT EmailType FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID) =  'Commencement'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsCommenceEmailFerpa END,
        IsAcctHoldEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN (SELECT EmailType FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID) =  'Account Holder'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsAcctHoldEmailFerpa END
    Where CMN_PersonsFerpa.cmn_personsID = (select cmn_personsID from CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID)
```

After few suggestions here is what I have. Is this acceptable? Or is there a better way?:

```
    SELECT @DBType = EmailType, @cmn_personsID = CMN_PersonsID FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID

    UPDATE dbo.CMN_PersonsFerpa 
    SET 
        IsWorkEmailFerpa = CASE WHEN @DBType =  'Work'  THEN @IsFERPA END,
        IsPersonalEmailFerpa = CASE WHEN @DBType =  'Personal'  THEN @IsFERPA END,
        IsParentEmailFerpa = CASE WHEN @DBType = 'Parent'  THEN @IsFERPA END,
        IsTempEmailFerpa = CASE WHEN @DBType =  'Temporary'  THEN @IsFERPA END,
        IsFAFSAEmailFerpa = CASE WHEN @DBType =  'FAFSA'  THEN @IsFERPA END,
        IsCSSProfEmailFerpa = CASE WHEN @DBType =  'CSS Profile'  THEN @IsFERPA END,
        IsCommenceEmailFerpa = CASE WHEN @DBType =  'Commencement'  THEN @IsFERPA END,
        IsAcctHoldEmailFerpa = CASE WHEN @DBType =  'Account Holder'  THEN @IsFERPA END,
        LastChangeBy = @UserGUID,
        LastChangeDateTime = GETDATE()
            Where CMN_PersonsFerpa.cmn_personsID = @CMN_PersonsID
```

Comment: Where is @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID coming from? Is it pulled from CMN_PersonsFerpa?

Comment: @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID is coming from front-end instead of either tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal would be to eliminate sub-queries. You could do so by building up a temp table before the update, or by using proper linking. Without knowing your data schema it is hard to help you design something, but here is a shot:

```
update p set 
    IsWorkEmailFerpa = case when e.EmailType = 'Work' then @IsFERPA else IsWorkEmailFerpa end,
    IsPersonalEmailFerpa = case when e.EmailType = 'Personal' then @IsFERPA else IsPersonalEmailFerpa end,
    IsParentEmailFerpa = case when e.EmailType = 'Parent' then @IsFERPA else IsParentEmailFerpa end,
    IsTempEmailFerpa = case when e.EmailType = 'Temporary' then @IsFERPA else IsTempEmailFerpa end,
    ...
    IsAcctHoldEmailFerpa = case when e.EmailType = 'Account Holder' then @IsFERPA else IsAcctHoldEmailFerpa end,
from  dbo.CMN_PersonsFerpa  p
    join dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks e
        on e.cmn_personsID = p.cmn_personsID
where e.CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID
```

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you use a join? Correlated subqueries work row by row like a cursor and almost never should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than running the query 8 times, run it once into a variable and perform cases on the variable itself.

Would look something like this:

```
SELECT @EmailType = EmailType FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID

UPDATE dbo.CMN_PersonsFerpa 
    SET 
        IsWorkEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN @EmailType =  'Work'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsWorkEmailFerpa END,
        IsPersonalEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN @EmailType =  'Personal'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsPersonalEmailFerpa END,
        IsParentEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN @EmailType =  'Parent'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsParentEmailFerpa END,
        IsTempEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN @EmailType =  'Temporary'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsTempEmailFerpa END,
        IsFAFSAEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN @EmailType =  'FAFSA'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsFAFSAEmailFerpa END,
        IsCSSProfEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN @EmailType =  'CSS Profile'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsCSSProfEmailFerpa END,
        IsCommenceEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN @EmailType =  'Commencement'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsCommenceEmailFerpa END,
        IsAcctHoldEmailFerpa = (CASE WHEN @EmailType =  'Account Holder'  THEN @IsFERPA ELSE IsAcctHoldEmailFerpa END
    Where CMN_PersonsFerpa.cmn_personsID = (select cmn_personsID from CMN_PersonsEmailLinks WHERE CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID = @CMN_PersonsEmailLinksID)
```

Comment: -1 What if the EmailType changes after the SELECT runs but before the UPDATE?